# ASP.NET Core 2.1 load razor page from text file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I would try to load in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application, some little pieces of views dynamically from a text file. This will allow me to load some specialized DIVs at runtime. Is there a way to make it runs or is a wrong way?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You 'can' do this by loading the text file contents into a string, then using the [@Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) directive to 'output' the HTML to the webpage.

However, you may want to consider if this is really the best method for achieving what you want. Text files and their loading can be both slow and rather insecure (wouldn't want someone opening the text file up in notepad and typing an offensive message for example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with you for the text files, but this is only a test :)

Thank you